# Canvas fabric.js renderAll makes white screen

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I have made photo editing web page and have this issue, **serious**.

I have made undo/redo code as follows.

```
  state = Stack.pop();
  canvas.fabric.loadFromJSON(state, function() {
    canvas.fabric.renderAll();
  });
```

And **clearing the full screen with white color** process is shown and that will push away lots of people.

I can remove this making another canvas but if then have to change whole structure of the webpage.

Is there any function in fabric.js to make it easily?

ex) display-previous-while-rendering?

Comment: I am afraid you need to change the undo redo logic and instead of rendering the whole canvas, you need to update only the changed properties

Comment: There can be various types of changes even background change and it's the same as whole rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the latest version fabricjs makes possible to do not make the canvas flash.
If you cannot use latest ( 2.0.0beta5 ) do the following:

```
fabric.StaticCanvas.prototype.clear = function () {
  this._objects.length = 0;
  this.backgroundImage = null;
  this.overlayImage = null;
  this.backgroundColor = '';
  this.overlayColor = '';
  if (this._hasITextHandlers) {
    this.off('mouse:up', this._mouseUpITextHandler);
    this._iTextInstances = null;
    this._hasITextHandlers = false;
  }
  this.clearContext(this.contextContainer);
  this.fire('canvas:cleared');
  this.renderOnAddRemove && this.requestRenderAll();
  return this;
};
```

Having the `renderAll` under `this.renderOnAddRemove` bool condition, will not make the canvas flash since the loadFromJson process set that boolean to false.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i have replaced `fabric.min.js`, `Undo` is doing without splash but `Redo` is doing with splash. All code is same , what is this issue?